# how to add a movieclip to second frame of main timeline through document class?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs3

i simply have one layer which has two frames

---

**frame 1** : menu with only one button

**frame 2** : blank but with document class want to put Movie Clip named circle

---

*I want to put it that way because i will program the symbol to draw ....(till now wrote nothing)*

**In document class till now i have written**

```
package
{
    //list of our imports these are classes we need in order to
    //run our application.
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.Stage;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class engine extends MovieClip
    {

        // moved ourShip to a class variable.
        private var ourShip:circle = new circle()
        //our constructor function. This runs when an object of
        //the class is created
        public function engine()
        {

            ourShip.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            ourShip.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
            addChild(ourShip)
        }
    }
}
```

First frame button as file :

```
package
{
//imports
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.SimpleButton;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
//-------

public class start extends SimpleButton
 {
   public function start()
   {
   addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onTopClick);
   addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, onBottomOver);
   }

   function onTopClick(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
     MovieClip(root).gotoAndStop(2)
   }

   function onBottomOver(e:MouseEvent):void
   {
       }
 }
}
```

By the way i only know addchild (which i wrote in as here,right now it would display circle in both frame 1 and frame 2 but i want it in only frame 2)

Comment: Please explain as i am new to whole flash and actionscript

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590717/only-add-child-to-current-frame

Answer (score -2):

Because of how the Flash timeline works, you can only add something to a frame when you are there. So you can do,

```
goToAndStop(3);
addChild(myClip);
```

But then if you leave frame 3 it is gone forever.

You can

- Add the code to the individual frame of the timeline, or
- You can create a simple Event listener like below

Adding Event Listener:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function() {
  if (this.currentFrame == 3) {
      addChild(myClip)
    }
 })
```

Comment: This is not entirely correct because Hamza last line says "only on frame 2". You can't add an object to a frame. You always add it to the entire timeline, so once you leave frame 2 it will still exist. See this question for a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590717/only-add-child-to-current-frame

Comment: You are right i will edit his answer to correct one , should i do that ??
this also works and i can edit answer to also add easier way making it a useful answer,should i edit answer and also mark it as answer ?

Comment: I am unsure what you are asking here. Let itcouldevenbeaboat take care of his answer. You answer the question yourself with your findings, or leave this as is because I linked to the another similar question.